# How to remove replaced character in input element when using input event and reg

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to discover why the `Backspace` is not able to remove the `-` from the text input? and Yes I have to use the  `input` event here and not any of `keyup` or `keypress`

**To test it:**

1. enter 111
2. the `-` will append to the input
3. try remove test by `Backspace`

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var number = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
  if (number.length == 3) {
    number = number.replace(/(\d{3})/, "$1" + "-");
  }

  $(this).val(number)
  $('input').attr({
    maxLength: 4
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Because when you press backspace, again `if (number.length== 3)` condition satisfies and Again replace function executes: `/(\d{3})/`

Comment: when you backspace, it handles the input as if it has length 3, hence it puts the - behind the value again

Comment: Either you change the event to change, focusout... or delay it's handling function.